# Resizing window weird behaviour using SFML

Tags: c++, user-interface, sfml

I am builiding a Minesweeper game, and now working on a feature to let the user change the difficulty level of the game.

Basically, I have a dropdown with options, which works fine, and I changed the number of rows, cols, mines, width of the window and height of the window, based on the choice:

(This is inside the game loop)

```
// Draw the dropdown options if the dropdown is open
        if (isDropdownOpen)
        {
            window.draw(dropdownBackground);
            for (auto& option : dropdownOptions)
            {
                window.draw(option);
                if (checkButtonPressed(window, option))
                {
                    std::string difficulty = option.getString();
                    numRows = difficultyMap[difficulty][0];
                    numCols = difficultyMap[difficulty][1];
                    numMines = difficultyMap[difficulty][2];
                    windowWidth = CELL_SIZE * numRows;
                    windowHeight = CELL_SIZE * numCols + MENU_HEIGHT;
                }
            }
        }
```

Then, the user continues to play in the current difficulty, until reset is pressed:

```
if (checkButtonPressed(window, resetButton))
        {
            window.setSize(sf::Vector2u(windowWidth, windowHeight));
            gameGrid = initGameGrid(numRows, numCols, numMines);
            guiGrid = initGuiGrid();
            setupMenu(font, menuBackground, resetButton, gameButton, dropdownOptions, dropdownBackground);

            gameWon = false;
            gameLost = false;
        }
```

Which, as you can see, resizes the window, and re-sets up everything.

Here is what goes wrong.
This is the initial window:

```
// Global vars
int numRows = DEFAULT_ROWS_NUM;
int numCols = DEFAULT_COLS_NUM;
int numMines = DEFAULT_MINES_NUM;
int windowWidth = CELL_SIZE * numRows;
int windowHeight = CELL_SIZE * numCols + MENU_HEIGHT;


// In the game function
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(windowWidth, windowHeight), "Minesweeper", sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close);
```

[image]

Now, after changing the difficuly to, begginer, which should be 9 * 9 rows, and adjusting like above the window sizes accordingly, this is what happens:

[image]

Which is weird, because it shrinks everything. For example, the cell sizes are constant. The thing is, it behaves as if it was filling the entire window. For example, clicking the bottom right of the window (White), reveals the bottom right cell.

I know my question might be confusing. So if anyone is willing to help, I can answer any clarifying questions any provide more information. Thank you!

---

Update 1:

`drawGrid` function:

```
void drawGrid(sf::RenderWindow& window, const std::vector<std::vector<sf::Sprite>>& grid)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[0].size(); j++)
        {
            window.draw(grid[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I am missing something, but it would be very helpful if you posted the function where you're actually drawing the grid.

Comment: Hm. My approach would be to look (ctrl + f) for all places where the size of the sprite gets changed. Apparently the sprites are just too small? Probably an error with the code where you calculate the sizes of the sprites. I have never really used SFML so I can't really help you that well, just putting my thoughts out there.

Comment: I've found a solution - I should just have updated the View. I'll addd an answer soon.